# Contact Form 7 - Add a Info Text to Checkboxes/Radiobuttons

Tags: forms, plugin-contact-form-7

I need a description to every Checkbox/Radiobutton. For Example Dancecourses.

`[checkbox* dancecourse use_label_element exclusive "beginner" "crashcourse" "another course" "another course"]`

I define the dancecourse name, but I need an Description for this course too.

How do I solve this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before the shortcode add:

```
<p>Your description here</p>
```

Comment: That will be hidden for screen reader software in _form_ modus.